# Selector for input checkboxes Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-forms, drupal-entities

I am trying to hide a field based on what user is selecting from a entity referenced checkbox list but no matter what I do I cannot hide the field.

I think some issue with the selector.

```
 $form['title']['#states']['invisible'][] = array(
  'input[name="field_offering_course[und][0][target_id]"' =>array('checked' => TRUE));
```

[image: Attached is the view source for the checkbox]

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a bracket:

'input`[`name="field_offering_course[und][0][target_id]"`]`' =>array('checked' => TRUE));

I can't help more than that...not very experienced in php :D